# Armazenar dados de uma variável que troca de valor a cada instante

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá, estou tentando resolver um problema que envolve suas questões.
Estou usando uma api em python para obter dados da plataforma de investimento IQ Option, porém não estou conseguindo trabalhar com os dados.

Se eu faço `dados = I_want_money.get_realtime_candles("EURUSD", 1)` a variavel `dados` fica alternando seu valor a cada segundo, por exemplo:

```
print(dados)
```

> defaultdict(, {1573598084: {'active_id': 1, 'size': 1, 'at': 1573598085007490313, 'from': 1573598084, 'to': 1573598085, 'id': 45579603, 'open': 1.10109, 'close': 1.10109, 'min': 1.10109, 'max': 1.101105, 'ask': 1.10115, 'bid': 1.10103, 'volume': 4, 'phase': 'T'}})

```
print(dados)
```

> defaultdict(, {1573598085: {'active_id': 1, 'size': 1, 'at': 1573598086007376567, 'from': 1573598085, 'to': 1573598086, 'id': 45579604, 'open': 1.101095, 'close': 1.1011, 'min': 1.101095, 'max': 1.1011, 'ask': 1.10116, 'bid': 1.10104, 'volume': 2, 'phase': 'T'}})

```
print(dados)
```

> defaultdict(, {1573598086: {'active_id': 1, 'size': 1, 'at': 1573598087007314295, 'from': 1573598086, 'to': 1573598087, 'id': 45579605, 'open': 1.101105, 'close': 1.10111, 'min': 1.101105, 'max': 1.10111, 'ask': 1.10117, 'bid': 1.10105, 'volume': 2, 'phase': 'T'}})

Então se eu faço por exemplo `aux = dados` a variavel `aux` vai se comportar da mesma forma.

Outro problema é que a variável a qual atribuo esses dados se torna do tipo `dict`, então se eu não consigo obter por exemplo `dados[volume]`.

Como faço por exemplo para armazenar em um vetor a cada segundo os dados de `dados` no campo `max` ?

Comment: Pelo que li na documentação da biblioteca, a comunicação é feita via websockets, então a biblioteca atualiza os dados em tempo real.
Essa pergunta não é sobre python, mas sim sobre o uso da API do IQ Option. (eu não conheço a API então não posso ajudar)

Answer (score -1):

Bom você pode fazer o seguinte, a cada segundo, atribua os valores que "dados" receber e coloque em uma lista.

```
values = []
while 1:
    dados = I_want_money.get_realtime_candles("EURUSD", 1)
    values.append(dados)

    if len(values) == 30:
        break

print(values)
```

Nessa lista você pode acessar os valores livremente